# What's the "best" Fleet composition for powering through sorties?

Tags: kantai-collection

I've hit a wall with my sorties and am unable to go past 2-4, both because my fleet never actually moves to the boss node, or when we get there, we are usually too weakened to stand a chance.

Currently my fleet consists of Haruna-FBB(flag), Akagi-CV, Aoba-CA, Yuubari-CL, Jintsuu-CL, and Shimakaze-DD all leveled in the high teens.

My question is what should I even be going for in a fleet composition to clear sortie 2-4? Am I just underleveled? Also, in general what is a good all-around fleet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

World 2-4 is one of the speedbumps you will meet.

A brute force fleet that is often recommended is the 4BB, 2CV fleet, bringing enough air power and heavy hitting high armor ships.

The routing on this map is also tricky in that getting a bad route, you will reach the boss with inssuficient Ammo and Fuel to make it.

Honestly, Ships that have not yet reached their Kai version and have not been modernised will on average not make it.

Comment: The heavy fleet is what I mainly used until sorties started requiring specific fleet comps. now stuck again because everyone else is massively underleveled, lol.

Comment: @Rapitor That is true, But unlocking World 3 (map 3-2 esp) and World 4 (map 4-3) does unlock some good spots for grinding CA, CL and DD and unlocking 2-5 gives you an extra shot at a medal for blue print purposes. You normally never return to 2-4 except for a few quests so the heavy fleet is a viable sacrifice.